# Increase iPad cache over 50 MB?

Tags: ipad, html, web-applications, offline-caching

I'm developing an offline webapplication using manifest and wondered about the maximum cache size on iPad. I made a few tests during which I was asked if I want to increase cache to 10 MB, 25 MB and 50 MB. So everything under 50 MB seems to be working (I disabled internet connection and after restarting Safari I could still navigate through the website). But above 50 MB is apparently not possible. Just to be sure: Does anybody know if it's possible to go beyond 50 MB?

Comment: I'm also interested in mobile browser limitations (as in linked question). I'm mostly interested in Local Storage, but offline cache is also an important factor. I hope someone will answer this question. By the way, did you make tests only on iPads or in iPhones too?

Comment: I only tested on iPad2 with iOS 4.3.

Answer (score 2):

50 mb is the iOS limit currently but this is likely to increase in the future and probably go limitless eventually.