# HTML5 Offline iPad App with Caching videos, PDF, Doc and PPT files

Tags: ipad, html, offline-caching, offlineapps, html5-appcache

Currently I am trying to build a web app for iPad which needs to be used in places with no internet connectivity. The app is includes some video files, PDF, Doc and PPT files so the total application size will be 100MB.

Initially I was planning to use HTML5's offline manifest caching to sync the assets to the iPad's memory when internet connectivity was available before going on the road, but unfortunately there appears to be a restriction (at least in iOS 3.2) that the cache can total no more than 5MB.

I am aware that there is no limit on Cache-Manifest in the HTML5 specification, but in most cases there is a total cache limit of about 5MB (with it varying from browser to browser), but this would not be enough for my needs.

Could you please help me to understand the best way to get this application done?

With the help of HTML5 and Web SQL Database / IndexedDB will I be able to do this?

Or the Native Application development is the only option?

Comment: There is 50 MB limit in iOS 5+. See [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8082930/increase-ipad-cache-over-50-mb?rq=1